# Angularjs button click with ui router is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angular js application. I am using ui-routing technique. I am facing issues in button click event. Below is my main.js file.

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

                $stateProvider.state('ForgotPassword', {
                    url: '/ForgotPassword',
                    templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.html',
                    controller: 'ForgotPassword'
                });
                             $stateProvider
                            .state('ForgotPassword.ResetPassword', {
                                url: '/ResetPassword',
                                templateUrl: 'ForgotPassword/ResetPassword.html',
                                controller: 'ResetPassword'
                            });
                      });
              });
```

Below is my forgotpassword.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Here i am injecting ResetPassword.html.
Below is my ResetPassword.html

```
  <div class="button-container">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit" data-ng-click="ResetPassword()">
  </div>
```

Above button does not work.
This is my Resetpasswordcontroller.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ResetPassword', ['$rootScope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($ResetPasswordService, $scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
        alert("Works");
        $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
            var sub = {
                mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
                dob: $scope.updateName
            };
            alert("does not works");
            var servCall = ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);
            servCall.then(function (data) {
            }, function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
            });
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Resetpasswordservice.js

```
app.service("ResetPasswordService", function ($http, $state) {
    alert("aaa");
    this.ResetPassword = function () {
        var url = '/api/projects/7';
        return $http.post(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

});
```

[image: FolderStructure]
$scope.ResetPassword is not working and i am not getting error also. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to find what goes where.. would be easier to help if a fiddle/plunker is made out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency injection order is wrong. Try this one:

```
    (function () {
        angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ResetPassword', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', 'ResetPasswordService',  function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, ResetPasswordService) {
            alert("Works");
            $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
                var sub = {
                    mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
                    dob: $scope.updateName
                };
                alert("does not works");

                $http.post('/api/projects/7').then(function (response) {
alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }]);
    })();
```

ResetPasswordService.js

```
    angular.module('RoslpApp').service("ResetPasswordService", function ($http, $state) {
    alert("aaa");
    this.ResetPassword = function () {
        var url = '/api/projects/7';
        return $http.post(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But now i am getting Cannot read property 'ResetPassword' of undefined

Comment: I am facing error in       var servCall = $ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);

Comment: Register your service like this:
 angular.module('RoslpApp').service('ResetPasswordService'). I am updating my answer.

Comment: This is also not working. Cannot read property 'ResetPassword' of undefined. Can i call api directly from controller? Can i bypass service?

Comment: Yes, you can call api from controller itself.

Comment: May i know how can i call?

Answer (score 2):

I think your arguments are wrong, try to change it to something like this (corresponding arguments):

```
[
    '$rootScope', 
    'ResetPasswordService',
    '$scope', 
    '$translatePartialLoader', 
    '$translate', 
    function ($rootScope, $ResetPasswordService, $scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate){
        [...]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

 myApp.controller("myController", ['$rootScope' , function( $scope){
  
   $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
     
            var sub = {
                mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
                dob: $scope.updateName
            };
            alert("does not works");
            var servCall = ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);
            servCall.then(function (data) {
            }, function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
            });
        }
  
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div ng-controller= "myController">
    <div class="button-container">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit" data-ng-click="ResetPassword()">
  </div>
    </div>
   
  </body>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

 myApp.controller("myController", ['$rootScope' , function( $scope){
  
   $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
     
            var sub = {
                mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
                dob: $scope.updateName
            };
            alert("does not works");
            var servCall = ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);
            servCall.then(function (data) {
            }, function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
            });
        }
  
 }]);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div ng-controller= "myController">
    <div class="button-container">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit" data-ng-click="ResetPassword()">
  </div>
    </div>
   
  </body>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller= "myController">
    <div class="button-container">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit" data-ng-click="ResetPassword()">
  </div>
    </div>

  </body>
```

There may be problme while passing the dependency to controller in passing the arguments to callback.I tried simple way with one arguments.its work to me.Check it

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below. Your order and reference is wrong.

```
angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ResetPassword', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate','ResetPasswordService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate,ResetPasswordService) {
        alert("Works");
        $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
            var sub = {
                mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
                dob: $scope.updateName
            };
            alert("does not works");
            var servCall = ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);
            servCall.then(function (data) {
            }, function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
            });
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting below error. [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ResetPasswordServiceProvider <- $ResetPasswordService

Comment: The name of the service is incorrect, you need to pass the actual name. Damn this dude was 20sec faster than me to answer ^^

Comment: show your service code, did you called the service file in index page

Comment: I think passing 'ResetPasswordService' (as I answered) should work if that's the name you gave it.

Comment: ok dude. service name is matter now. But i haven't see service name, he only knew right?

Comment: Now i am facing issues in service. I am not able to call    var servCall = $ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);

Comment: app.service("ResetPasswordService", function ($http, $state).. What is $state? just remove this

Answer (score 0):

Change you ResetPassword.html code as following:

```
<div class="button-container">
   <input type="button" value="Submit" id="input-submit" ng-click="ResetPassword()" />
</div>
```

Also, edit you controller as the problem is due to **incorrect dependencies order**. You should rewrite as:

```
(function () {
angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ResetPassword', ['$ResetPasswordService','$scope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($ResetPasswordService, $scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
    alert("Works");
    $scope.ResetPassword = function () {
        var sub = {
            mobilenumber: $scope.updateID,
            dob: $scope.updateName
        };
        alert("does not works");
        var servCall = ResetPasswordService.ResetPassword(sub);
        servCall.then(function (data) {
        }, function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.data));
        });
    }
}]);
})();
```

Comment: Hope the first alert is getting prompted(alert("Works");)

Comment: If  remove $ResetPasswordService my code works fine.

Comment: Yes. There is no such service provided by angular. Although, you create your own service(for making http calls), and can use it in controller.

Comment: If i put angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('ResetPassword', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $ResetPasswordService) {
 my code will work but i cant call service

Comment: Yes. As i said, there is no such service provided by angular($ResetPasswordService). If you want to use, you have to create by your own. Also, do remember to inject it properly, then only you will be able to access that service. In case or in correct injection, you ll get an error(injector incorrect).